# UISplitviewController and different UIKeyCommands depending on master, detail or both being on screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uikeycommand

I want to include some `UIKeyCommands` in my app. My app consists of one `UISplitViewController` that forces the master to be always visible on iPad full screen. On smaller screen it works like it normally would.

Now, I've implemented some `UIKeyCommands` in the `MasterViewController` and some in the `DetailViewController`. However, the app will only show those in `DetailViewController`. So I put all of them in the `RootSplitViewController`, but that will show all of them, even when the `MasterViewController` is hidden in iOS 9's splitview.

What I want though, is for it to show all when the app is fullscreen on iPad and thus the `MasterViewController` is forced on screen together with the `DetailViewController`. And when the view is small (ie 50-50) and the `MasterViewController` is hidden, I want it to only show those of the window that's on screen.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I managed to do this - although in a not-so-pretty way.

The `UIKeyCommands` are added to the `RootSplitViewController`.

```
- (NSArray *)keyCommands {
    if (self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular) {
        return @[
                    [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"r" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(changeRestaurant:) discoverabilityTitle:@"Change restaurant"],
                    [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"t" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(changeTable:) discoverabilityTitle:@"Change table"]
                ];
    } else {
        if (self.masterIsVisible == YES) {
            return @[
                         [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"t" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(changeRestaurant:) discoverabilityTitle:@"Change restaurant"]
                    ];
        } else {
            return @[
                         [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"t" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(changeTable:) discoverabilityTitle:@"Change table"]
                    ];
        }
    }
}
```

Those methods call the actual methods in the specific `UIViewController`.

```
- (void)changeRestaurant:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    RestaurantController *master = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [master changeRestaurant];
}

- (void)changeTable:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    TableController *detail = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [detail changeTable:sender];
}
```

In order for this to work I added a `BOOL` to the `UISplitViewController`.

```
@interface RootSplitViewController : UISplitViewController

@property (nonatomic) BOOL masterIsVisible;

@end
```

Which is then called in the `MasterViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    RootSplitViewController *rootView = (RootSplitViewController *)self.splitViewController;
    rootView.masterIsVisible = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    RootSplitViewController *rootView = (RootSplitViewController *)self.splitViewController;
    rootView.masterIsVisible = YES;
}
```

I know this might not be the pretties method, but it works. If anyone knows a better way to do it, I'd love to hear your feedback.